# How long does your dead body or excess pals stay in the world?

Tags: palworld

When you die, and are playing at a certain difficulty and settings, everything you are holding is dropped to the ground, usually right where you had died. This would leave an X marking where you died. If you have a completely full palbox and you attempt to catch a new one, you drop a shining Pal Sphere containing the pal you just caught. This leaves an X marking where you caught the pal.

There was also a time where I was fighting a boss and it overpowered me, killing me. I returned unarmed trying to get back to my body to recover my items and died again. Both sets of items remained and I was eventually able to recover it. So apparently you could potentially have multiple "dead bodies" in the world. You could have many multiple pals in the field when you have a full palbox.

What's the limit? There was a difficulty setting if I remember correctly indicating how many items stay in the world.

How long does your dropped inventory stay on the field? Is it the same for dropped pal spheres with a pal in it? What about other regular items that are on the ground? How do they contribute to the item limit?

Comment: It looks like leaving the (single player) world would cause the dropped items to disappear completely. So be sure to collect them before leaving, or else you will lose them.

Answer (score 0):

The default "Maximum Number of Dropped Items in a World" is 3000, and I just noticed that one of my Death Chests disappeared.

I currently have 9 Red X-es active, so that might be the limit with that Dropped Items limit?